# Shortest way to get unique sequence in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence

I have a JavaScript code that generates a pattern based on an array.

Array below:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

will return:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

However, I want the pattern to be simplified and only get the unique sequence which is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Is there any way I can achieve this with `slice()` or `filter()`?
If not, then any suggestions on how I can?

Please do take note that the array pattern and the unique sequence will be variable in length.

Comment: First I would ask, what a sequence is. How do you define one?

Comment: What if we just adding another number to the end, would that then mean there is just one sequence?

Comment: @keith, yes that would be the case.

Comment: In your example, you could just diving the array into 2, and compare.  could the sequence be 3,4,5.. etc?

Comment: @keith, as stated in my question, the yielded pattern could be of variable length, the pattern can have 8 indices like [4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1] and I just need the [4, -1] since it is the unique sequence.

Comment: You said the arrays could be variable length, not the sequence.

Comment: @keith, editing my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, about the other answer. I was fast.

```
// Ask the original sequence as parameter
function uniqueSequence(originalSequence){

    return 
        originalSequence
        .map(function(value, index){                            // Get difference between each number.
            return value - originalSequence[index - 1];         // Somthing like [1,2,3,2,1] => [NaN, 1,1,-1,-1]
        })
        .toString()                                             // Parse that result to string format => "NaN,1,1,-1,-1"
        .match(/N((,[0-9-]+)*?)\1*$/)[1]                        // we look for the shortest pattern of comma-separated integers 
                                                                // (,\d+) starting right after "NaN" and repeating till 
                                                                // the end of the string. Result in something like => ",1,1,-1,-1"
        .substring(1)                                           // Remove the first comma => "1,1,-1,-1"                                    
        .split(',')                                             // Convert to array ["1","1","-1","-1"]
        .map(function(value){
            return parseInt(value);                             // Parse each element to integer [1,1,-1,-1]
        });
}
```

In shortest code (ES6)

```
 f=_=>_.map((a,i)=>a-_[i-1]).toString().match(/N((,[0-9-]+)*?)\1*$/)[1].substring(1).split`,`.map(a=>~~a)
```

```js
f=_=>_.map((a,i)=>a-_[i-1]).toString().match(/N((,[0-9-]+)*?)\1*$/)[1].substring(1).split`,`.map(a=>~~a)

// Ask the original sequence as parameter
function uniqueSequence(originalSequence){

    return originalSequence
        .map(function(value, index){                            // Get difference between each number.
            return value - originalSequence[index - 1];         // Somthing like [1,2,3,2,1] => [NaN, 1,1,-1,-1]
        })
        .toString()                                             // Parse that result to string format => "NaN,1,1,-1,-1"
        .match(/N((,[0-9-]+)*?)\1*$/)[1]                       // we look for the shortest pattern of comma-separated integers 
                                                                // (,\d+) starting right after "NaN" and repeating till 
                                                                // the end of the string. Result in something like => ",1,1,-1,-1"
        .substring(1)                                           // Remove the first comma => "1,1,-1,-1"                                    
        .split(',')                                             // Convert to array ["1","1","-1","-1"]
        .map(function(value){
            return parseInt(value);                             // Parse each element to integer [1,1,-1,-1]
        });
}

console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
console.log(uniqueSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this does?

Comment: could you please explain the `/N(` part of the regexp? Also, wouldn't the "substring(1)" part produce wrong result if the first item in the pattern is negative?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn, that's what I was thinking too. But maybe I can tweak this a little to produce the results I want.

Comment: @witherwind, I got it: after calculating the difference between each item and its previous item (in a `map` method) the first item of the pattern is always `NaN`. The regular expression then looks where this `NaN` in the string representation of the array ends and the actual pattern begins. So no problem with negatives. Clever! :)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it is quite a clever codegolf approach to my problem. I'm still bothered with the extra loop iteration by using map, but I can play around with this to fulfill my needs.

Comment: @witherwind Sorry, I added a full explanation to the code. An explanation to the regex can be found on any regex tester.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 functions working together, the concept is we want to take an incrementally bigger slice of the original pattern and see if it repeats evenly across the original pattern.

```
function getUniquePattern(pattern) {
    // Test an incrementally large slice of the original pattern.
    for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        // Take a slice to test
        var attempt = pattern.slice(0, i);

        // Check if the slice repeats perfectly against the pattern
        if(sliceIsRepeatable(attempt, pattern)){
            // Return the matched pattern
            return attempt;
        }
    }

    // Return an empty array for failures
    return [];
}

function sliceIsRepeatable(slice, pattern) {
    // Slice length must be a multiple of the pattern's length
    if(pattern.length % slice.length !== 0 ) return false;

    for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        j = i % slice.length;
        if(pattern[i] !== slice[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

getUniquePattern([1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the shortest way, but it's simple.  And hopefully easy to follow, I've placed some comments to help show what it's doing.

```js
const test1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1];
const test2 = [4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1];

function getSeq(a) {
  //lets try diving the array by length / 2, then each
  //time use bigger and bigger chunks.
  for (let chunks = a.length / 2; chunks >= 1; chunks --) {
    const chunksize = a.length / chunks;
    //can we divide equally?.    
    if (chunksize % 1 !== 0) continue;
    //lets compare all chunks are the same
    let found = true;
    for (let lpchunk = 1; lpchunk < chunks; lpchunk ++) {   
      for (let offset = 0; offset < chunksize; offset ++) {
        if (a[offset] !== a[offset + lpchunk * chunksize]) {
          found = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    //we have found a duplicate lets return..
    if (found) {
      const dups = [];
      for (let offset = 0; offset < chunksize; offset ++) {
        dups.push(a[offset]);
      }
      return dups;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getSeq(test1).join(", "));
console.log(getSeq(test2).join(", "));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work against different patterns:
console.log(getSeq([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]).join(", "));